# About ambiguous functions

Tags: functions

I've read this: A function is well-defined if it gives the same result when the representation of the input is changed without changing the value of the input. For instance, if f takes real numbers as input, and if f(0.5) doesn't equal f(1/2) then f is not well-defined (and thus not a function) .

Could you give me an example of an ambiguous function so that it becomes clearer to me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A particularly nasty example is the "function" on the reals that reports the first digit of $x$ beyond the decimal point. So 
$$
f(1/2) = f(0.5) = 5 \\
f(1/3) = 3 \\
f(7) = f(7.0) = 0
$$
and so on.

The problem (and the reason I put "function" in quotation marks) is that "the first digit of $x$ beyond the decimal point" isn't well-defined. For instance, the numbers 
$$
1.999\ldots
$$
and 
$$
2.0000\ldots
$$
are the same real number (this takes a little bit of knowledge of infinite series!), but one representation has a "9" after the decimal, and one has a "0" after the decimal.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as an ambiguous function. Every function is well-defined, or it is not defined at all.

That said, we often say that a function is "well-defined" in circumstances similar to what you say ('representation of the input is changed without changing the value on the output').

More formally, if you have a set $S$ and an equivalence relation on $S$ (say, $\sim$), it is well known that you can construct the quotient $S/_\sim$ - the set of all equivalence classes. Now, if $T$ is another set, and if you want to define a function $f:S/_\sim\to T$, you would often first define a function $F:S\to T$ and then say $f(s/_\sim)=F(s), s\in S$, i.e. you would define the function $f$ on the whole equivalence class of $s$ to take the value of $F$ on $s$. This is a correct definition (and so we can say for $f$ that it is "well-defined") if, for any other $\sigma\in S, s\sim\sigma$ (so $s/_\sim=\sigma/_\sim$) you have $F(s)=F(\sigma)$.

Here is a contrived example of a function that is not well-defined. (Or rather of a failure to define a function.)  Try to define $f:\mathbb Z_2\mapsto \mathbb Z_3$ by setting $f(x\pmod 2)=x\pmod 3, x\in\mathbb Z$. This is incorrect because $0\equiv 2\equiv 4\equiv\ldots\pmod 2$ but $0\not\equiv 2\not\equiv 4\pmod 3$, so for example, it is not clear what $f(0/\equiv)$ is. However, change $\mathbb Z_2$ to $\mathbb Z_6$ and the definition is then fine, because $x\equiv y \pmod 6$ implies  $x\equiv y \pmod 3$ for $x,y\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0):

You started the example yourself.  If we declare that $f(0.5)=3, f(10/20)=5$, then viewing $f$ as a function from reals to naturals we have a problem.  If we view $f$ as a function from text strings to naturals that returns the length of the string it is a fine function.  To properly define a function you have to specify the domain, though often it can be inferred from context.

A more clear statement is that to be a function it should return an unambiguous value for every item in the domain.  In your example the domain is the reals, or the rationals, or the positive rationals, or something like that.  In that domain $0.5=1/2$ so the function values need to agree.